# iTextSharp PDF Stamper outputting corrupted PDFs

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdfstamper

I am using iTextSharp's PDF Stamper to add a rectangle to the bottom corner of the PDF with some text inside of that box. This  works great sometimes, but other times I get an error opening the PDF and it's corrupted. I'm wondering if anyone can see something I am doing wrong. Here is my code that reads an existing PDF and save a stamped PDF as a copy.

```
using (var reader = new PdfReader(_InputFileName))
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_OutputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (PdfStamper PDFStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fileStream))
        {
            Rectangle cropBox = reader.GetPageSize(1);
            Rectangle bottomLeft = new Rectangle(80, 20);
            EmptyTextBoxSimple(PDFStamper, 1, bottomLeft, BaseColor.ORANGE);
            ColumnText columnText = GenerateTextBox(PDFStamper, 1, bottomLeft);
            columnText.AddText(new Phrase(_StampText));
            columnText.Go();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check that _InputFileName is a valid PDF File to start with? If the input has already some corruption than iTextSharp could make that worse. Did you try to use a newer (or older) version of iTextSharp?

Comment: @JohannesKrackowizer Yes. I can confirm the input PDFs are valid and open fine.

Comment: @JohannesKrackowizer also I was on v5.5.13.1 and updated to v5.5.13.3 and experienced the same issue

Comment: Then I assume the error is somewhere in EmptyTextBoxSimple or GenerateTextBox.

Comment: Did you check the corrupt PDFs with a simple texteditor and looked just at the first line that should look something like %PDF-1.4 and the end of the pdf file should contain xref and then a list of all streams and their position in the file and the gneration number and at after that you should find the "trailer" and %%EOF. And did you try to parse the pdf with a tool like https://github.com/dzzie/pdfstreamdumper ?

Comment: @JohannesKrackowizer thank you for that info. I can open the PDF in Notepad++ and see a lot of unprintable characters but it starts with "%PDF-1.4" on the first line and ends with "endobj", "xref", and a list, then "trailer", looks like some data, "%iText-5.5.13.3" tag, "startxref", a number, then "%%EOF" to end it. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243796/discussion-between-johannes-krackowizer-and-dvo).